# Posting content in radEditor using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, telerik, radeditor

I am using JavaScript to post html content inside radEditor field upon opening the modal Edit window.

The content displays only in the 'HTML' tab of the radEditor and is blank in 'Design' mode.

```
var radPrompt = $find("<%=tFieldsEdit_radPrompt.ClientID%>");
radPrompt.set_html(prompt);
```

According to Telerik it is supposed to have "Real-time HTML View - if you make a change in either the WYSIWYG or the HTML window, the other one will be automatically updated.".

When the modal Edit window loads the tFieldsEdit_radPrompt field is blank since 'Design' is the default mode.

I only see the content when I switch to 'HTML' tab. When I toggle back to 'Design' or 'Preview' it is blank.

Any clue as to why it is blank in 'Design' & 'Preview' modes?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get a JavaScript error when loading the editor in the modal Edit window?

My suggestion is to see how this demo is implemented, because the set_html method works as expected when loading the editor in RadWindow dialog:

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/editorinradwindow/defaultcs.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, this issue is happening only in Firefox (current version 18.0.1) & on a modal window.

I viewed it in IE8 & Safari and the content displays correctly in 'Design' & 'Preview' mode.

I am not using RadWindow or RichEditor. I am using the standard RadEditor.

Comment: If the problem is reproducible in Firefox only call the editor.onParentNodeChanged() method when showing the editor in the modal dialog. See this forum for more information: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/editor/radwindow-radmultipage-radeditor-no-content.aspx